# How to resolve the error when adding an entity reference relationship?

Tags: 7, views

Multifield Contributed Module - https://www.drupal.org/project/multifield

Company Content Type has multifield

1) Company Division - Entity reference
2) Company Categroy - list

While adding relationship as entity reference node company division in views an error is thrown.

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'field_fieldname_node.id' in 'on clause'

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your issue is because of the [Multifield](https://www.drupal.org/project/multifield) issue [Add Views API integration for the multifield field type](https://www.drupal.org/node/2041533). And that the [patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/multifield-2041533-96.patch) attached to [comment nr 96 of this issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2041533#comment-11246925) solves it.